# Understanding the difference between uniform convergence , convergence everywhere and almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to get the intuition behind convergences .

I understand **convergence in distribution** and **convergence in mean-square error**.

However I'm vague about the difference between 
- **almost sure convergence** and **convergence in probability** 
- **convergence everywhere** and **uniform convergence** .

I get the concept with some examples and I struggle to understand with respect to another . Is there a reference or a more generalised example to understand these concepts better ?

Or if anyone who is comfortable with the concepts exists, please do explain. 
thanks.